# Unknown http requests of type http://<domain>/cache/<32-digit-alphanumeric-key>

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7.5, httpmodule

I am getting a lot of incoming requests with this structure:

> //domain_name/cache/22092e9b25c40809dfb94b6179166b26.

I am running a .NET 4.0 website served from IIS 7.5. A lot of these URLs have no referrer URLs  and come in randomly with a different 32 digit alphanumeric key. And I do not have any resource like '.../cache/...' on my website.

I just want to eliminate such requests and want to understand where these are coming from at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Might be a variation on a session fixation attempt (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation), where an arbitrary key is pushed to the server for later misuse. This URL structure is probably meangingless to ASP.Net, but it might represent a vulnerability on some other platform.

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks for the response. But what does /cache/ have to do with session fixation. Also without revealing too much I would like to add that I have eliminated Session from my site(as in no Session cookie or SID's).

Comment: In the same manner that session can be fixated, perhaps the attack is attempting to do the same with some cache directory (which is irrelevant to ASP.Net, but the attacker may not know that). It's just a guess; I see many malformed URLs coming into my ASP.Net servers, but I have not seen this type of request.

Comment: @TimMedora Also I would like to add that I get around 100 such requests in a time span of 10 minutes, and all these lead to a Application_Error, which I am handling, but I do want to eliminate them as it will keep my servers less busier and more attentive for good requests.

Comment: If all the requests come from the same IP, consider adding a firewall rule. If not, the impact of 100 requests in 10 minutes will be hardly noticeable (though I completely understand wanting to eliminate them).

Comment: I am already doing the IP blocking. Another thing, atleast 50% of these requests seem to have a referrer url which seems to emanate from the google search results page or a display ad run for one of the links on our site. Any clues on that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. There is a chance that it could be legitimate traffic. Maybe someone else will post an answer with more info.

Comment: I posted [the same question on the Webmasters Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30066/chrome-causing-404s-ending-with-cache-hex-string) a few months back. Judging by the bug report it looks like an extension that went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Chrome browser had a bug (Issue 132059:) http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=132059
for specific versions (19.0.1084.52-2 19.0.1084.56 not with 18.xx)

BUT:
i found on my server, that CHROME users, still sending those requests, even with NEWER chrome version. (Chrome/22.0.1229.94)

**Logs from 2012-10-21**

> 188.6.141.189 - - [21/Oct/2012:08:51:04 +0100] "GET /{{MYPAGE}}/cache/99e668d4c3ad55d2f2c876540bf3e7e6 HTTP/1.1" 200 16307
>   "http://{{MYSERVER}}/{{MYPAGE}}" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94
>   Safari/537.4"
>
> 95.233.53.220 - - [21/Oct/2012:08:55:01 +0100] "GET /cache/4d8f7265aa32291438a3a9b9e158f843 HTTP/1.1" 404 1376
>   "http://{{MYSERVER}}/{{MYPAGE}}" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1)
>   AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94
>   Safari/537.4"
>
> 80.99.63.141 - - [21/Oct/2012:08:56:34 +0100] "GET /{{MYPAGE}}/cache/575c44ac6fcb338b52bac212665cb165 HTTP/1.1" 200 16307
>   "http://{{MYSERVER}}/{{MYPAGE}}" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1)
>   AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94
>   Safari/537.4"
>
> 78.1.148.185 - - [21/Oct/2012:08:56:41 +0100] "GET /{{MYPAGE}}/cache/3ee13ff1e23d8873ddb0e0042c6a3910 HTTP/1.1" 200 16229
>   "http://{{MYSERVER}}/{{MYPAGE}}" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94
>   Safari/537.4"
>
> 80.180.181.64 - - [21/Oct/2012:09:00:41 +0100] "GET /cache/c4f56b1faa9ea9bb7789728409bfc21f HTTP/1.1" 404 1376
>   "http://{{MYSERVER}}/{{MYPAGE}}" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94
>   Safari/537.4"
>
> 79.36.123.193 - - [21/Oct/2012:09:05:19 +0100] "GET /cache/11ff17cacc601d7ee9790cb2933e86c9 HTTP/1.1" 404 1376
>   "http://{{MYSERVER}}/{{MYPAGE}}" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0)
>   AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94
>   Safari/537.4"
>
> 5.102.21.234 - - [21/Oct/2012:09:06:54 +0100] "GET /{{MYPAGE}}/cache/fc8ccc9bd6e960b7e4f4af0165e839a6 HTTP/1.1" 200 16386
>   "http://{{MYSERVER}}/{{MYPAGE}}" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1)
>   AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94
>   Safari/537.4"
>
> 149.210.41.194 - - [21/Oct/2012:09:07:05 +0100] "GET /{{MYPAGE}}/cache/4e4055517809a8bbc8de1acb4ee9e560 HTTP/1.1" 200 15998
>   "http://{{MYSERVER}}/{{MYPAGE}}" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0)
>   AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94
>   Safari/537.4"

It might be,

1] Chrome still have this bug i mentioned.

2] Some Chrome ADD-ON/EXTENSION is sending those requests.

Comment: thanks a lot for that answer. Guess I will have to wait till Chrome solves this bug and live with these malformed incoming requests until then.